# Looking up value in one table to update another

Tags: join, filter, conditional-statements, lookup

I have one table that has user IDs, another table that as AD groups; certain AD groups tell you whether the client is a member of VIP, Pilot, Remote Access etc groups.

When trying to create a view that shows which of these groups a client is a member of, I am running into the issue of having to create a separate join for each group name since not doing that is creating duplicates in result.

```
Table One
Client_ID   Client_Name
---------   ------------
A               ABC
D               DEF
G               GHI

Table Two:
Client_ID      AD_Group
---------      --------
A               I_GroupX
A               GroupY
D               B_GroupX
D               GroupZ
G               GroupY
G               GroupZ

Result Table:
Client_ID       Client_Name      VIP(X)     Pilot(Y)       RemoteAccess(Z)
---------       -----------      ------     --------        -----------
A                 ABC            I_GroupX     GroupY           Not Member
D                 DEF            Not Member   GroupY            GroupZ
G                 GHI            B_GroupX     Not Member        GroupZ
```

This works but would have to create one for each group instead of all in one view:

```
SELECT Client_ID,
      ,Client_Name
      ,[VIP] = CASE
       WHEN A.GroupX IS NULL THEN 'Not Member'
                             ELSE A.AD_Group
       END
  FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      (SELECT [Client_ID]
             ,[AD_Group]
        FROM Table2
       WHERE  [AD_Group] LIKE '%GroupX') A 
    ON Client_ID = A.Client_ID
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Client_ID, Client_Name,
[VIP(X)] = ISNULL((select AD_Group from Table2 where Client_Id = t1.Client_ID and AD_Group LIKE '%GroupX'), 'Not Member'),
[Pilot(Y)] = ISNULL((select AD_Group from Table2 where Client_Id = t1.Client_ID and AD_Group LIKE '%GroupY'), 'Not Member'),
[RemoteAccess(Z)] = ISNULL((select AD_Group from Table2 where Client_Id = t1.Client_ID and AD_Group LIKE '%GroupZ'), 'Not Member')
FROM Table1 t1
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. We are almost there as this gives a yes or no if someone is present in one of the AD Groups. Problem I have is that I need to list the AD Group name since a pilot client could be IT Pilot, or Business Pilot, with corresponding groups named IT_GroupX and Bus_GourpX, hence the need to look for LIKE '%GroupX' and returning the group name

Comment: Ah OK. So I have changed the `SELECT CASE` to an `ISNULL()`. Any good now?